# Trouble understanding $p$-values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, interpretation

In my textbook $p$-values are defined as follows:
$$p\text{-value} = P(T \text{ is at least as extreme as } t \text{ given } H_0 \text{ is true}) $$

where $T$ is the test statistic. It goes on to say that

> The smaller the $p$-value, the stronger the evidence against $H_0$.

Here is my issue. Surely if the probability that $|T| \geq t$ is smaller then the probability that $|T|<t$ is larger. That is, the values are more likely to congregate about $0$. This would provide **greater** evidence of the null hypothesis.

Comment: There are already so many posts time and again here that can be used to mark this as a duplicate. Have you checked any one of those?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the responses in the other posts.

Comment: Maybe it helps to focus on the meaning of small t and capital T: t is what you see in the data. T is what you would see if you do the experiment again and again. If $P(|T|>t)$ is small, then you have observed something rare in your data.

Comment: Smaller p provides greater evidence *against* the null hypothesis. You are writing of "evidence of the null hypothesis" by which you may mean (but I'm not sure) "in its favour!?